# Android: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android

I got a Fatal EXCEPTION: main.

I believe that my exception is caused by the following code:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        Log.d("Button", "Login");
            SONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(name, password);

        // check for login response
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
        ....code body
```

And here is my Logcat

```
08-20 18:41:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(4240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 18:41:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(4240): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-20 18:41:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(4240):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
08-20 18:41:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(4240):     at   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
08-20 18:41:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(4240):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
```

When I change the code to following, I got no Exception.

```
Log.d("Button", "Login");
//JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(name, password);

try {
        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
code body.....
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: You are performing network related operation on the min ui thread which is not possible.

You can use `threads` or `asynctask`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to use asynctask.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 3.0 and higher (I may be wrong), you will get an error for doing this on the main thread because your UI may freeze. It is recommended to handle this in an asyncTask as seen here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

**Note:** If you are new to Android, please realize that async tasks are super important and should be learned as soon as possible. This is what will give your application a smooth UI. Another reason you may want to use AsyncTask is for anything involving a database in android (sqlite).

Comment: StrictMode is since 2.3 actually.